# Linq to Entities Remove without fetching

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Can this code:

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    IEnumerable<Setting> settings = db.Settings.Where(s=> s.UserId==Uid);
    db.Settings.RemoveRange(settings); 
}
```

Be written in some way that there would be no need for fetching first? something like:

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Settings.Remove(s=> s.UserId==Uid); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) Library which offers you to write the below query:

```
//delete all Settings where UserId matches
db.Settings.Where(s=> s.UserId == Uid).Delete();
```

Docs:

> A current limitations of the Entity Framework is that in order to
>   update or delete an entity you have to first retrieve it into memory.
>   Now in most scenarios this is just fine. There are however some
>   scenarios where performance would suffer. Also, for single deletes,
>   the object must be retrieved before it can be deleted requiring two
>   calls to the database. Batch update and delete eliminates the need to
>   retrieve and load an entity before modifying it.

Comment: the link is not correct. I added the nuget packag for EntityFramework.Extended but I'm not seeing any delete methods

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani You need to add the using statement to see the extensions. I updated the link for reference.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Of course it can be done:

If `UserId` is primary key:

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    Setting settingToRemove = new Setting { UserId = Uid };
    db.Entry(settingToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If `UserId` is not the key *you have to query database*, but what you need is just *get primary keys* according to UserId.

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    List<int> settingIdsToRemove = db.Setting
        .Where(m => m.UserId == Uid)
        .Select(m => m.Id)
        .ToList();

    foreach(int settingId in settingIdsToRemove)
    {
        Setting settingToRemove = new Setting { Id = settingId };
        db.Entry(settingToRemove).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: how can it be used for a range?

Comment: I am sorry, I thought `UserId` is a key, I didn't pay attention to IEnumerable. It can be done if you know PK. You can get PKs according to UserId then delete them in foreach loop. I will edit my answer.

Comment: would you please join me in chat? [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120954/azerbaycan)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to spend time in foreach loop the only way to do it is

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(..)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx